# Align vertical text with the above bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bar chart, where the bars are vertical. The text on the bottom is also vertical, I want to align the vertical text with the above bars, so that the text is aligned with the bars.

HTML

```
<div class="progress-bars vertical-bars flat">
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress-track">
      <div class="progress-fill">
        <span class="percentage">90%</span>
        <span class="skill-name">Football</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVgdPx), to see the entire picture.

Now my vertical text is aligned a little chaotic. How I can align the bottom text with the vertical bars I have?

Comment: I don't understand. What is your exact issue with what you have? The spacing?

Comment: @KaiChristensen if you look in the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVgdPx), the vertical bottom text is not centered with the bars, should be aligned with the bars on the same line, hope this helps you to have a better understanding

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: how about using text-align in CSS?

Comment: @laish129 I can't use `text-align` as they are rotated 270deg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the final pleasant alignment by using this css code:

```
.vertical-bars .progress-fill .skill-name {
    bottom: -30px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
    transform-origin: 0 50% 0;
}
```

#### [Demo](http://codepen.io/farskid/pen/eJoNdb)

#### UPDATE:

The `transform-origin` of value `0 50% 0` will make sure the text rotates around its starting point and then using `translateX` we could easily transfer the text exactly as much as its width to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean align with the white lines?
Try adding a 'right:-7px' to .skill-name (might need the px value tweaking)

Edit: Farzad YZ 's answer is so much better :)